# Error Website publish failing due to file path being too long

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem when I try to publish web
Can you help me with this?
Please!

[image: image description here]

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2988,5): Error : Copying file Scripts\Highcharts-4.0.1\exporting-server\java\highcharts-export\highcharts-export-web\target\classes\com\highcharts\export\controller\ExportController.class to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Scripts\Highcharts-4.0.1\exporting-server\java\highcharts-export\highcharts-export-web\target\classes\com\highcharts\export\controller\ExportController.class failed. **The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have only one way:

that directory `obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Scripts\Highcharts-4.0.1\exporting-server\java\highcharts-export\highcharts-export-web\target\classes\com\highcharts\export\controller\` should have shorter name. This is a restriction for 260 symbols for file path and name in OS and for 248 for the directory name.

This name already has 189 symbols, but you have to add to that length rest of the path. Like C:\web\inetput\sitename...